# histogram overlayed inside pytorch tensor image

Tags: image, pytorch, histogram, overlay

I have a pytorch tensor image. I want to find the histogram for each channel and overlay the histogram image on top of the original image (in a corner). It would be useful if I can get the overlayed image as a tensor itself. How can I get that?

There is a longer way of doing this by first getting the histogram, save the histogram as image, read the histogram image as tensor, then replace a region of the original tensor image with the read histogram image tensor.
There has to be an easier way than this.

Comment: Is this a question about plotting? If so, you should specify which plot library you are using (and then the question probably has nothing to do with pytorch).

Comment: @cheersmate Matplotlib for plotting the image, would be okay. I would like to have the final overlayed image as tensor itself for a particular downstream task.